# Installing error in Google Cloud using CloudML library in R

Tags: r, installation, keras, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying Google Cloud for the first time for training a DNN model with using Keras in R.

The use of the `cloudml_train()`-function try to install a lot of libraries on the Google Cloud server, and there is an error that I can't go round:

```
master-replica-0 Installing BiocGenerics (0.20.0) ...  
master-replica-0 curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

As I understand, it tries to install the BioGenerics library, but the path is wrong.

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Sometimes 3rd party repositories can be a bit flaky. Can you wait a bit and try?

Comment: I waited as you suggested. Slept on it. And today it just started to work! Thanks! Of course, no idea what happened meanwhile...

Comment: I don't know about CRAN, but some 3rd party repositories are somewhat flaky so installing 3rd party packages can cause problems. Were working on solutions that might avoid this dependency in the future and increase the reliability.

Comment: @SándorZsebők did you solve this issue?